# Change border color depend values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have couple of div and textbox. I want to change div border color. It's depend textbox values. But textboxes are sometimes increases sometimes decreases they are not a certain number

I tried this but doesn't work

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var val=document.getElementById('a').value;
if(val==25){
$(".b").parent().css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid yellow"});
}
else if(val==50){
$(".b").parent().css({"color": "black", "border": "2px solid red"});
}
});
```

```css
.abc { 
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  color: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="container">
  <div  class="abc">
        <input type="text" class="b" value="25" id="a"/>
  </div>
  <div class="abc">
        <input type="text" class="b" value="50" id="a"/>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for here. Please revise to explain the expected behavior better. What should happen if the value is 26?

Comment: You have two inputs with the same id, which is bad.

Comment: So use a range?

Comment: I want to change div border color, depend of textbox value

Comment: That is what you did..... it only does it onload. I assume you want to do it when user changes it? So add a change event listener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few problems with your code:

- The `if` and `else-if` statement will run only once when the document is loaded. You should attach event listener to that.
- You have two elements with same `id="a"`. Ids are always unique in whole page
- You should convert `val` to number using `+`(In this case its fine because of double equal `==`).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input').on('keyup',function(){
  let val = +this.value;
  console.log(val)
  if(val === 25){
    $(this).parent().css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid yellow"});
  }
  else if(val === 50){
    $(this).parent().css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
  }
  else $(this).parent().css({"color": "", "border": ""});

})
$('input').keyup();
});
```

```css
.abc { 
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  color: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="container">
  <div  class="abc">
        <input type="text" class="b" value="25" id="a"/>
  </div>
  <div class="abc">
        <input type="text" class="b" value="50" id="b"/>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for answer but textbox value fill automatically

Comment: @CelalBahadırKAYA Its unclear what you mean. Please explain I will try to help.Tell what should happen

Comment: I think this is only half correct. The function should be called right away in case the default values equal the conditional values. In your answer, the borders should *start* as yellow and red because the values equal the conditional values. This also only works a single time. If you try to change the values after it's triggered once, it will keep them yellow and red regardless of what's entered.

Comment: @Nick If you mean that they are the text box is yellow still if you change `25` to `255`. So that is fixed. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: @CelalBahadırKAYA You only want to change the `border-color` once(when the script is executed)?

Comment: @MaheerAli no, When textbox value change border-color will be change

Comment: @MaheerAli Thanks for your helpful answer

Answer (score -1):

If this is for css border color change here it is. I used an animation loop and all I had to do was change colors over time. You'll see. It's very simple and quite effective.

```
#Title{
animation: colorchange 2s infinite;


}

@keyframes colorchange{
0%{border: 5px ridge blue;}
50%{border: 5px ridge green;}
100%{border: 5px ridge mediumseagreen;}
50%{border: 5px ridge purple;}
}
```

Comment: This question got answered over one year ago. Besides this is not what OP wanted. OP wanted to change the `border-color` based on the value of the input field. Not an animation.

Comment: oh ok never knew.